# Adding SSL encryption to TidTCPServer/TidTCPClient

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy10

I'm adding SSL encryption to an existing project in Delphi 7 using a TCP Server and Client with no certificates. I've attached the required SSL `IOHandler`s in each program, set the `PassThrough` to False in the `OnConnected`/`Execute` procedures, and the error I get during a connection attempt is:

```
Error connecting with SSL.
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure.
```

Using OpenSSL 1.0.2 DLL's, latest Indy10 from GitHub. I've used SSL with `TIdHTTP` with no issues.

I've been reading every search item on the subject but cannot find a solution.

Here is the TCPServer DFM.

```
    object TCPServer: TIdTCPServer
    Bindings = <>
    DefaultPort = 2323
    IOHandler = SSLHandler
    OnConnect = TCPServerConnect
    OnDisconnect = TCPServerDisconnect
    OnException = TCPServerException
    OnListenException = TCPServerListenException
    OnExecute = TCPServerExecute
  end
  object SSLHandler: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL
    SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmServer
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    SSLOptions.Versions = [sslvTLSv1_2]
  end

procedure TVTServerForm.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).Passthrough := False;
end;

procedure TVTServerForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Cmd := Trim(AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn);
  if Cmd = 'Login' then etc
```

TCPClient DFM...

```
  object TCPClient: TIdTCPClient
    IOHandler = SSLHandler
    OnDisconnected = TCPClientDisconnected
    OnWork = TCPClientWork
    OnConnected = TCPClientConnected
    ConnectTimeout = 10000
    IPVersion = Id_IPv4
    Port = 2323
    ReadTimeout = 100000
    Left = 728
    Top = 468
  end
  object SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    Destination = ':2323'
    MaxLineAction = maException
    Port = 2323
    DefaultPort = 0
    ReadTimeout = 100000
    SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmClient
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]
  end

procedure TMainForm.TCPClientConnected(Sender: TObject);
var Ret: string;
begin
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(TCPClient.IOHandler).Passthrough := False;
  TCPClient.IOHandler.Writeln('Login');
  Ret := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  etc
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using. Make sure you are using **TLS** and not **SSL**, as SSL is no longer secure. What you described *should* work, although on the server side the `OnConnect` event would be more appropriate than the `OnExecute` event to set `PassThrough` unless the client is sending a `STARTTLS`-style command first.

Comment: I've tried all the SSLVersions but now set to only sslvTLSv1_2 on both sides. Just tried setting Passthrough in server OnConnect... TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).Passthrough := False;
but made no difference. Don't really have any code as I'm using components on a form. I tried adding a CipherList but no difference. I've tried the Mode set to sslmServer on the Server side and sslmClient on the Client side with no change. Is there something else I can send you?

Comment: Sometimes I notice the error is different...
error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
There is no documentation about the SSLOptions that I can find. It just says each setting is a Property and that's it. I assume I don't need to adjust VerifyMode or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, you do have some code, please show it, as well as your DFM settings for the Indy components on the Form.

Comment: I think I've added all I can to the original post. Anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Perhaps I should mention the Host is being set to localhost in the TCPClient, and everything works fine when I leave PassThrough at True, but of course that defeats the purpose.  It seems to be a bug in the Indy code?

Comment: Are you using the same DLLs on both sides? Are they the latest 1.0.2 release, 1.0.2u? One thing I find odd is how you were able to get `SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions = [sslvTLSv1_2]` at the same time, because that should be impossible. Setting `Method` to `sslvSSLv23` updates `SSLVersions` to `[sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`, and setting `SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1_2]` updates `Method` to `sslvTLSv1_2`. `sslvSSLv23` is used for version negotiation, so `Method` should never be `sslvSSLv23` when `SSLVersions` contains only a single version.

Comment: The DLL's say version 1.0.2.20. I don't know what letter version that is.  If .0 is "a" then .20 is "u".

Comment: That is exactly what the last number in the version means.

Comment: I manually entered the SSLVersions above since I'm actually assigning that in the code somewhere and just entered it as if it was in the DFM to save space/time.  The Method will be automatically changing to sslvTLSv1_2.  Sorry for the confusion.
The SSL DLL's are working when used in a TIdHTTP client.  
 It seems the server end isn't working.

Comment: then you should have posted the actual DFM and code as-is, not a modified version of it.

Comment: "*It seems the server end isn't working*" - Since you did not show the details of the actual handshake, I can only guess what is happening. But IIRC, you need a server-side certificate, unless you set the server SSLIOHandler's `CipherList` to an anonymous cipher that doesn't require a certificate.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I searched for anonymous ciphers and can't really find anything.  I found some pages with ciphers but not labelled as anonymous and didn't make any difference.  I tried the one on this page but same error.
https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256/
Do you know of one that works?

Comment: when setting the `CipherList`, make sure you follow the format described in [OpenSSL's ciphers documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html)

Comment: What I have tried entering is how they appear when running openssl ciphers -v -tls1.  Entering an invalid format produces an exception EIdOSSLSettingChipherError, so I know the format is correct.  I guess it's just not supported and I will need to use certificates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250118/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ross).